# Unable to access headers from axios call

Tags: .net, reactjs, axios

I'm working on a React-Redux app using axios to make my REST calls.  I'm trying to inject a token into the Authorization header for the .NET REST API to use to verify the call.  I've tried multiple way to send the headers but none of them seem to work.  I've even tried fetch with no luck.  I can see the header listed in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' property of the HTTPRequestMessage object, but no way to see or access the value.  When I send it using Postman, the Authorization header is set properly.  Here's the React code:

```
function callApi(endpoint, authenticated, data) {
  let token = localStorage.getItem('id_token') || null;

const api = axios.create({method: 'POST', headers: {'Access-Token': `${token}`, 'Authorization': `${token}`,  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}});

 //return fetch(BASE_URL + endpoint, config)
 return api.post(BASE_URL + endpoint, config)
    .then(response =>
      response.text()
      .then(data => ({ data, response }))
    ).then(({ data, response }) => {

      if (!response.ok) {
        return Promise.reject(data);
      }

      return data;
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Here's the .NET console where you can see that the Authorization header is null:

```
request.Headers
{Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US, en; q=0.8, de; q=0.6
Host: localhost:3001
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-token, authorization
}
    Accept: {*/*}
    AcceptCharset: {}
    AcceptEncoding: {gzip, deflate, sdch, br}
    AcceptLanguage: {en-US, en; q=0.8, de; q=0.6}
    Authorization: null
    CacheControl: null
    Connection: {keep-alive}
    ConnectionClose: null
    Date: null
    Expect: {}
    ExpectContinue: null
    From: null
    Host: "localhost:3001"
    IfMatch: {}
    IfModifiedSince: null
    IfNoneMatch: {}
    IfRange: null
    IfUnmodifiedSince: null
    MaxForwards: null
    Pragma: {}
    ProxyAuthorization: null
    Range: null
    Referrer: {http://localhost:8080/}
    TE: {}
    Trailer: {}
    TransferEncoding: {}
    TransferEncodingChunked: null
    Upgrade: {}
    UserAgent: {Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36}
    Via: {}
    Warning: {}
```

And here's where I have the CORS entries in the web.config:

```
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization, X-Custom-Header, Access-Token" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization, X-Custom-Header, Access-Token" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Thanks for checking things out!